State doesn't change
When I login, the state doesn't change but it should change.
This is my Composable:
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val userState by viewModel.userState.collectAsState()

    when (val currentState = userState) {
        is AuthenticatedUserState.Success -> {
            val user = currentState.user
            Column {
                if (user != null) {
                    Text(text = user.message)
                }
            }
        }

        AuthenticatedUserState.Error -> {
            Text(text = "Error: Something went wrong!")
        }

        AuthenticatedUserState.Loading -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
            viewModel.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
}

This is my ViewModel:
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel
@Inject constructor(
    private val sessionRepository: SessionRepository,
    private val context: Context
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _userState =
        MutableStateFlow<AuthenticatedUserState>(AuthenticatedUserState.Loading)
    val userState: StateFlow<AuthenticatedUserState> get() = _userState
    private val validateLogin = ValidateLogin()
    var loginState by mutableStateOf(LoginState())
    var errorMessageState by mutableStateOf("")
    var isLoggedIn by mutableStateOf(false)


    private fun updateUserState(newState: AuthenticatedUserState) {
        _userState.value = newState
    }

    /**
     * Starts the login process using the provided login form data.
     * Upon completion, the authResult is being handled
     * @author Reshwan Barhoe
     * @param loginForm login data that's being passed
     */
    private fun login(loginForm: AuthenticationRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val authenticationResult = sessionRepository.login(loginForm)
            handleAuthResult(authenticationResult)
            userIsLoggedIn(loginForm)
        }
    }


    fun userIsLoggedIn(loginForm: AuthenticationRequest) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = sessionRepository.loggedIn(loginForm)
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val token = response.headers()["set-Cookie"]
                    val sessionIdToken = fetchSessionIdToken(token)
                    saveAuthToken(sessionIdToken)
                    fetchAuthenticatedUser("Bearer $sessionIdToken")
                } else {
                    _userState.value = AuthenticatedUserState.Error
                }
            } catch (error: HttpException) {
                _userState.value = AuthenticatedUserState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveAuthToken(token: String?) {
        context.getSharedPreferences("token", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit {
                putString("auth_token", token)
            }
    }

    private fun fetchSessionIdToken(cookieHeader: String?): String? {
        if (cookieHeader != null) {
            val sessionIdStartIndex = cookieHeader.indexOf("token=")
            val sessionIdEndIndex = cookieHeader.indexOf(";", startIndex = sessionIdStartIndex)
            if (sessionIdStartIndex != -1 && sessionIdEndIndex != -1) {
                return cookieHeader.substring(
                    sessionIdStartIndex + "token=".length,
                    sessionIdEndIndex
                )
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    private fun fetchAuthenticatedUser(token: String?) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                if (token != null) {
                    authenticatedUser(token)
                }
            } catch (error: Exception) {
                Log.d("Error", error.message ?: "Unknown error")
                _userState.value = AuthenticatedUserState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun authenticatedUser(token: String) {
        val authenticatedUserResponse = sessionRepository.getUserFirstName(token)
        val authenticatedUserDetails = authenticatedUserResponse.body()
        try {
            if (authenticatedUserResponse.isSuccessful) {
                _userState.value = AuthenticatedUserState.Success(authenticatedUserDetails)
                println("user state: ${userState.value}")
            }
        } catch (error: HttpException) {
            _userState.value = AuthenticatedUserState.Error
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the AuthResult for certain scenario's
     * @author Reshwan Barhoe
     * @param authenticationResult AuthResult that's being handled
     */
    private fun handleAuthResult(authenticationResult: AuthenticationResult<Unit>) {
        when (authenticationResult) {
            is AuthenticationResult.Authorized -> isLoggedIn = true
            is AuthenticationResult.UnAuthorized -> setErrorMessage(R.string.login_invalid_credentials.toString())
            else -> setErrorMessage(R.string.error_message.toString())
        }
    }
}

And the state holder class:
sealed class AuthenticatedUserState {
    data class Success(val user: AuthenticationMessage?) : AuthenticatedUserState()
    data object Loading : AuthenticatedUserState()
    data object Error : AuthenticatedUserState()
}

Tt should change the state to Success but the state stays at Loading.

When writing your question there's a preview option. Please use it to make sure your code formatting isn't all over the place :)

you can use a single state instead of three different AuthenticatedUserState, and always put the viewState changing function into the ViewModel class

Your code looks fine at the first glance. Can you add a Log.d statement below println("user state: ${userState.value}") and see if it gets called? Maybe there is something wrong with the Login logic so that _userState.value = AuthenticatedUserState.Success(authenticatedUserDetails) never gets called.

@Dodge_X Using both a userState and a private _userState is a convention, so I think this is intentional in this case.

I added a Log.d below println("user state: ${userState.value}") and i get this Success(user=AuthenticationMessage(message=Kees)) but on the screen i see the circular indicator.

I just used koin for dependency injection and it works, so it looks like that it doesn't work with dagger hilt and i don't know why can someone help me with this?
